# DropDown Isset IF statement to move entire record MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php. I have a dropdown option. I want to put an if statement that if one of the options is selected e.g. 'Completed' then I would like it to get the entire record from the MySQL table and move it to another table with the same table structure.
This is what i have so far:

```
 <?php

if( $_GET['status'] = 'Completed' ):

$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO second_table select * from first_table where id = id;



   status = ?,  
   day_id = ?,
   eta = ?,
   c_notes = ?
   WHERE booking_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('sissi',
   $_GET['status'],
   $_GET['day_id'],
   $_GET['eta'],
   $_GET['notes'],
   $_GET['id'] 
);






$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();

?>
```

Comment: How is this not working for you? And why a separate table? Wouldn't it just be easier to put a new field into the original table to signify that it's "done"/"completed" or whatever that the second table represents?

Comment: I think all you need to do is add another statement for:
DELETE from first_table where id=id;.  Once you're finished at least.

Comment: And, Marc B is correct - that's actually a cleaner thing to do.  Then all your data is still in once place and easy to filter.

Comment: I think it should change .<<<if( $_GET['status'] == 'Completed' ):>>>

Comment: Im I not closing the statement properly in anyway, im i missing anything, as dreamweaver shows something missing

Comment: Currently the script is doin nothing, its not inserting anything into the new table

Answer (score 0):

If the two tables have the same structures I think your query should be

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO second_table VALUES (SELECT * FROM first_table WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id'] );
```

Let me know if this didn't work.